# Ensuring a task is always re-run when any of its dependents are not UP-TO-DATE in gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a multi-project gradle repo with separate projects for handing database migrations (`schema`) and code generation (`codegen`). The `schema` project has a `:migrate` task for applying migrations to a database, and the `codegen` project has a `:generate` task, which depends on a migrated database, to generate some java code. For the sake of example, lets say a third project exists which depends on `codegen:generate`, named `app`.

In CI, the gradle build makes use of a remote build cache. This works well in most cases. Changes within `schema` cause a run that looks like this:

```
./gradlew app:build

> schema:migrate
> codegen:generate
> app:build

SUCCESS
```

Changes to only `app` also works well:

```
./gradlew app:build

> schema:migrate UP-TO-DATE
> codegen:generate UP-TO-DATE
> app:build

SUCCESS
```

The problem exists when there are changes within the `codegen` project, but no changes to `schema`:

```
./gradlew app:build

> schema:migrate UP-TO-DATE
> codegen:generate
  (Error here because a migrated database does not exist in CI,
   because `:migrate` did no work)

FAILURE
```

How can I ensure that `codegen:migrate` is always re-run when  there are changes to either `schema` or `codegen`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `migrate` should run when there are `codegen` changes, then those are inputs.

I would merge the `schema` and `codegen` projects into one, then configure the inputs such that the files that trigger `generate` to run are also declared as `inputs` of `migrate`.